# Is advising unfairly-treated newbies to use other SE sites okay?

Tags: discussion, migration, etiquette

For example, I am thinking of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496444/gcc-complains-about-large-adress-aware-trying-to-complile-qt-on-mingw64).

In my opinion, this question (and its answer) got a groundless unfair treatment.

But everything happened normally - at least, in theory.

I think, in a similar case, it would be a possible work-around of the problem if I would try to send the visitor to another SE site, where they can get (again, in my opinion) a friendlier, fairer treatment, even some up-votes.

I am asking here for a theoretical approval of this handling of similar problems.

Comment: What's unfair about downvoting someone for not doing any research, which is explicitly mentioned on the downvote arrow? Your premise is flawed. Another flawed premise is that we should cater to everybody and that a SE goal is to be "friendly" - it's not, SE sites are expected to be _useful_, and possibly non-offensive, but "friendly" is not an objectively measurable thing. I'd say the commenters told OP that the question is crap _in a friendly way_, what more do you want?

Comment: @l4mpi I want fair treatment with good-standing newbies. But this is offtopic, just as your comment: my question is not about this treatment is okay, my question was about advicing them to better directions is okay.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm telling you _your premise is flawed_. It's a bad question, users _should_ get downvoted everywhere on SE for asking bad questions. The correct thing to do here would be to teach OP why their question is lacking and how to ask better questions. Furthermore, the treatment _is_ fair - we downvote everybody who asks bad questions equally. And while you could argue that a downvote is "unfriendly" or rude or whatever, it is actually an integral part of the SE model, without which the sites would fare considerably worse as a useful resource.

Comment: @peterh Your question is essentially "Is it ok to direct people to other SE sites?". All the stuff about (un)friendliness is unnecessary to your core question, and removing it will most probably save you from "off topic communication".

Comment: @Yannis but then there is nothing left - the reason he wants to send people elsewhere because SO isn't "friendly" enough (meaning bad questions get downvoted as they should), which is of course not grounds for migration.

Comment: @Yannis Ok, but it is an important part of the problem, that they were treated on the rules, but this were (on my opinion) unfair and unneeded hostile. Thus, the rules are on the first side - and my opinion-based deed is on the second, which doesn't hurts the interests of the SE, but maybe hurts the interests of the SO.

Comment: @l4mpi No, the reason is to help new users to remain at least in the SE Network, after they were essentially expelled from the SO. And there is a second reason, to motivate the SO community to find more ways to correct newbie behavior instead of expelling them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you think is *unfair* about this situation? The poster didn't do sufficient research, therefore their post was downvoted. In what way is that "groundless unfair treatment"?

Comment: @JonSkeet The user wasn't capable to find the important message in the compiler output. Could you elaborate, what had been a "sufficient research" in this case?

Comment: @l4mpi If a question happens to be on topic on a different site and has received a poor response on SO, I don't see why it shouldn't get migrated.

Comment: @Yannis I am suspecting, they won't be migrated, because it would take away content and users from the SO. But I don't have any evidence, it is only a suspection. BTW, I am happy to give an upvote for your pro-migration argument.

Comment: @Yannis because that's a huge indication that it's a bad question, and migrating bad questions is explicitly discouraged.

Comment: "Wasn't capable of" or "didn't try"? There's *no* indication of effort within the question itself, and as soon as you separate "command" from "results" the error is pretty simple to see.

Comment: @l4mpi That's true in general, and it's also true for the question in question. However, there are exceptions. The much more focused communities of the smaller sites might see something more to the question that the SO crowd did. All this of course assumes that the question is actually on topic on another site, a requirement that excludes most of the outright crap questions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Even to try that needs the knowledge of the gcc flags, and an experience with similar build scripts. The OP didn't have this.

Comment: You don't need to have experience with a language before you can learn it. The OP should've done some research.

Comment: @peterh: No, it doesn't. It's been *ages* since I've used gcc, but reading `2/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--large-address-aware'` didn't take much effort. The OP just didn't put effort into writing a good question (or solving the question themselves before asking it). As such, the treatment wasn't unfair, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, with your knowledge and also with mine. Maybe you could try to remember to the very beginning where every error message was a chaotic mess.

Comment: @peterh: Yes, I remember that - and I still expect newcomers to *make an effort*. Did the OP explain that they'd tried to understand the error and failed? No. Did the OP explain what they'd tried to fix the error? No. Also bear in mind that if someone is brand new to development, they really shouldn't be trying to use several external libraries straight away - so either they're in *miles* over their head already, or they should have enough experience to read a pretty clear error message. *It's just a bad question.*

Comment: @JonSkeet What could have he done on _his_ level? Googling for a chaotic mess? He didn't get meaningful results if he isn't able to extract the important part of the compiler output. I didn't had a problem with an elitist direction of the SO, but then it should have been stated clearly, and not packaged into a fake "minimal effort needed" rule.

Comment: @peterh: this has nothing to do with newbies. This has everything to do with *effort*. If a newbie comes with a basic question but has shown in their question that they have made a good-faith effort to resolve the issue themselves, they'd get upvoted. You are making assumptions about why a post is being downvoted that don't hold.

Comment: @peterh if you consider comments about whether the OP in question was *"unfairly treated"* to be off-topic, and any discussion of it *"not constructive"*, then **don't mention it in the question**. Had you just asked *"is it acceptable to suggest alternative SE sites for a question"*, which appears to be the core of what you want to know, then you wouldn't have made the question's reception part of the topic. Also, this is not SO-specific, so should probably be on MSE (may already be a dupe there).

Comment: @peterh: your choice of words make it *very much* on-topic to discuss what is 'friendly' or 'unfriendly', just like for any X-Y problem question. You have made incorrect assumptions about why downvotes are being given, once you understand why this happens you can help users new to the Q&A format far better. Usually that doesn't involve sending them somewhere else.

Comment: @peterh: You seem to be *assuming* that the OP has no experience - that's not clear from the question. Even if the OP *is* a complete newbie, they should be capable of saying "I tried to understand the error message, but I couldn't do so" which would have made the question a *lot* better. This isn't a matter of being elitist - it's a matter of expecting people to make an effort and *show* that effort, regardless of their experience level. There's nothing fake about requiring people to put some effort into asking a question with all the relevant information about their problem.

Comment: @peterh: I have read all your responses so far, and Jon's comments, and I am adding my voice to the discussion. You don't need to repeat what you said to Jon.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I give the clear context, it doesn't mean the whole context should be ontopic. MSE is not okay, first becuase there I can't risk a similar crowd-downvoting as here, and second, because it is mainly an SO-specific problem (SO is far the worst in this sense between any SE sites known to me).

Comment: @peterh either the context is relevant (this feature, whatever you have in mind for it, is specifically for use whenever a question is treated *"unfairly"*), in which case discussion of your premise is perfectly reasonable as it is necessary to establish what questions would be eligible, or it isn't (the feature could be used for *any* Q that might fit better elsewhere), in which case leave it out. Meta votes don't affect your rep, there's no *"risk"*, it's just part of the consensus-building process.

Comment: @peterh: I don't think you are being at all receptive to anything anyone is saying here though. I am getting a distinct *talk to the hand* vibe from you, so I'll just leave this be. But **five respected members** of this community have been trying to help you understand fundamental premises of how Stack Overflow works, and you are rather stubbornly refusing to listen to anyone. The voting on your question is another indicator that, maybe, perhaps, you misunderstood something here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much your corrections! I consider this as big honor. But that sentence is also an important part of the context, so I needed to get it back.

Comment: Does this question actually have anything to do with [tag:software-recs-se] ?

Comment: @TZHX I think it is the best example if questions are closed based on non-trivial rules, because a newbie don't have any reason to think, his question like "With which tool could I do ...?" will be probably closed and deleted on the spot, despite it could be migrated to softwarecs SE.

Comment: @peterh: Angry remarks about downvotes on your question have _no_ place on SO, especially not in the question. Talk about _"not constructive"_...

Comment: @Cerbrus I think, politeness dictates to give at least a fair reasoning with a clearly visible cooperative intention after a similar rollback.

Comment: The reason this question is getting downvoted is because of you being extremely unwilling to listen to what people trying to help you are saying. The question is getting downvoted because of the completely irrelevant question you linked to. Comments about _"Look at how this question is being downvoted"_ simply don't belong on questions on the SE network. Never has, never will.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, it is an important argument. I think, maybe this sentence was an important part of the context, and I think, it had got nearly exactly so many downvotes even if it hadn't been there. But, on a normally functioning meta site, this sentence really hadn't been needed.

Comment: The downvotes are because you're adding irrelevant information to the question. Your comment assumes the downvotes mean _"Advicing unfairly treated newbies to other SE sites is not okay."_ That comment is completely irrelevant. So what? Now Meta SO is dysfunctional?

Comment: @Cerbrus No, a good question often needs to show a more wide context, in most cases a single-sentence, purely theoretical questions aren't enough clear, especiially not on the metas.

Comment: Sure, but the added context ___has to be relevant.___ The linked question doesn't benefit from being migrated, it's just rubbish.

Comment: I'd upvote if I only read the title, but after reading the post, I'd downvote since I agree with others that your premises are wrong. I always recommend users who mistakenly post an "Android usage" on SO to [android.se], not because they are friendlier, but because it's the correct site. Your linked post, however, is on-topic and more suitable on SO (it's about tools used in programming). They downvote because of no-effort-by-OP (the error message is already there, did the OP realize?)

Comment: @AndrewT. On my opinion, the no-effort rule was unfairly applied here. As you can see, it is a minority opinion here. But this question wasn't about the correctness of the opinions, it was about the "legality" of the advice.

Comment: @peterh: The majority of the users on meta, so far, seem to agree that the linked post lacked effort. In fact, I have yet to see someone beside you think otherwise. Doesn't that make you think that your opinion might be incorrect?

Comment: @Cerbrus Of course no, I would be glad to chat about its reason, but I think this chat would produce only unneeded hostility here.

Comment: So, the fact that a majority disagrees with your opinion doesn't make you question your opinion? Not even a little bit?

Comment: @Cerbrus Maybe this should depend on their arguments, and not on their number? :-)

Comment: Sure, but your only argument is your opinion...

Comment: Scrap my previous comment. After re-reading the title of this post, I wouldn't even upvote it since the premise is already wrong. **Focus on the post, not on the user**. If the post is on-topic there, let their communities handle and moderate that. SO community is generally helpful. Beside me, I often see people who recommend user to post on other site because it's the *correct site* based on on/off-topic, not because of their community's behaviour.

Comment: @peterh regarding the sentence you are determined to keep in: it would be helpful to clarify *what behaviour you're referring to*. None of the comments or answers so far offer any objection to comments referring OPs to alternative SE sites **if the question is a better fit** (nor should they, IMO; I certainly do it). Trying to put good questions in the best place is good for everyone, and is behaviour we encourage. Moving bad questions around isn't. It might be worth chatting with the community on your proposed destination site, to see how happy they'd be with that question turning up there.

Comment: See, for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93440/248731; http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/691; http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2712

Comment: It should be noted that suggesting reposting a question that gets closed and down voted on other sites can be a very bad experience for the user. "... But JohnSmith told me it would be ok on U&L. Why do I have to post on SuperUser now?"  Getting bounced around and pushing poor questions from one site to another is something we should strive to avoid rather than encourage.

Comment: @MichaelT The downvotes and the close of the question is the bad experience, and not my advice to re-post on a better place.

Comment: @peterh having a poor question closed on multiple sites is a worse one. Especially if the other site says to go back to the first one with a proper question.

Comment: @Cerbrus No, my argument is that new people not knowing the exact rules should get a fair treatment, and my second argument is that if a question is closed because of lack of minimal understanding, then this is what should be communicated and not some other.

Comment: @AndrewT. The posts are created by users. By living people. You can "focus on the post", you can blindly hostile and unfair with newbies (because you "focus on the post"), but fairness dictates, if you reason your action, give the real reason. If you close a post, if you downvotes a post, because of "lack of effort", despite your real reason is the lack of minimal understanding, I can't see that as fair treatment.

Comment: @MichaelT Right, but this is because I advice him into sites, which are well-known to me and I think his question had a better chance on them.

Comment: @peterh the question, as written, will get down voted on all sites. Read the mouse over for the down vote. It shows a lack of research. That needs to be rectified before it will remain open anywhere. I doubt its survival on U&L and would likely see such questions closed (migrate, but poor quality). The expectations for questions are stated multiple times in the tour and help center. If those are ignored, what outcome do you expect?

Comment: @MichaelT I am really sorry to replay myself, maybe you didn't read the whole thread until now. Your actual comment was here talked about five times already. I suggest to read them, and upvote which you agree.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer your question:

**Is advising unfairly-treated newbies to use other SE sites okay?**

Yeap, if someone posts an off-topic question that has a better fit on a different SE site, feel free to give the OP some advice on how to improve the question and where to post it.

Now, the question you linked is simply bad. It lacks research effort, and can't possibly be improved to be on-topic on any SE site. Frankly, I don't see the point of linking to that question in this post.

Comment: Although I disagree with your opinion about the linked question, your answer is a clear about my question. Thus I am happy to upvote and accept that.

Comment: But, advising people who post about problems compiling stuff on Windows to the Unix & Linux site should probably be avoided. Be sure that a question would actually be acceptable on the site you're suggesting.

Answer (score 34):

To answer your question:

**Is advising unfairly-treated newbies to use other SE sites okay?**

No, it is not. Let's assume for a moment that the user was unfairly treated. In that case directing them to other sites is not a solution for the issue. If his question was good and on-topic and the question got closed incorrectly, it needs to be reopened. If it got downvoted where it should really have received upvotes, you can upvote it. That addresses the unfair treatment. Telling them to take it somewhere else doesn't do them justice, nor does it improve the site.

But ...

If the treatment has not been unfair, telling them to take it somewhere else on the network only moves crap around for other sites to deal with. Only if we're dealing with an edge case which is off-topic on the current site, but good and on-topic on an other, should you advise them to take it somewhere else. And if you do, always make sure you know that it's good for the other site, and advise them to read through the help center to establish that for themselves.

Comment: It works only if my opinion is not a minority opinion. But what to do if it is? What if - on my best opinion - other SE sites are much more fair? What if I don't "move crap to other SE sites", but save worthy content and to-be-expelled user? What if on my opinion I do the second?

Comment: Reflect on your opinion.

Comment: @peterh That you think the question you're talking about is worthy of all this effort somewhat suggests that your opinion will be in the minority.

Comment: If you are really "saving worthy content from a to-be-expelled user" there is either something fundamentally wrong with the site, or with your understanding of it. Which one of the two it is only you can determine. I will assume good faith on your behalf, but would probably disagree on your view.

Comment: Assuming the newbies were indeed treated incorrectly, your answer appears to be more accurate than mine.

Comment: Your answer is fair enough @Cerbrus. I just don't want user who stumble upon this question to get the wrong impression. The question asked here makes certain assumptions that don't seem to pan out.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @Bart Not surely - opinions may differ, and sometimes you are alone with your opinion, but it is not always a reason to revoke that.

Comment: @Bart I am sorry, but honoring differing opinions, even if they are minority opinions, is a good practice. Changing our opinion _only_ _because_ _it_ _is_ _said_ _to_ _you_, is a bad practice.

Comment: Stubbornly holding on to an opinion when _everyone_ disagrees, is a bad practice. At very least question it. Or give a good reason why you're opinion is correct, instead of simply saying it is.

Comment: You are of course allowed to have your opinion. And I'm not forcing you to change it (as if I even could). You'd just have to ask yourself at some point if running head first into a concrete wall (with spikes) is something you want to keep doing. But your opinions are yours to keep.

Comment: @Cerbrus I gave. On the example question, the "lack of own effort" rule was unfairly applied, because on the level of OP _anything_ had been impossible, which you had accepted as "effort". Thus this rule essentially had mean an elitist SO, which is declaratedly _not_ the case (I weren't against a change into an elitist direction, it had to be stated very clearly).

Comment: "something I don't agree with" != "elitist". You use that word rather carelessly.

Comment: The OP could've searched for `unrecognized option '--large-address-aware'`. Seeing as he's using multiple libs, that should've been easy to the OP. You're making assumptions about the experience of the OP, there.

Comment: @peterh your argument boils down to "OP is [new/stupid/five years old/mentally challenged/etc], so we should completely ignore all of SEs quality requirements and instead upvote the question". Which is of course complete BS. SE and SO _do_ have quality requirements, and if a user is unable to meet them, this does not mean their low quality post is suddenly acceptable or exempt from downvoting. If it was imposible for OP to do anything (your words!) then they should start by going over the basics of the task they are attempting; which is of course too broad for SO.

Comment: @peterh I love how you say "on the level of OP anything had been impossible, which you had accepted as "effort"", while Jon Skeet told you he would've accepted "I tried to understand the error message, but I couldn't do so". Is that really beyond the level of a complete newbie? come on.

Comment: @Patrice Maybe he didn't mentioned it explicitly, but on my opinion, from the question it was clearly visible it is his problem. I mention again: I had _no_ problem if the site had a "minimal understanding required" rule, but in this case it had to be stated _clearly_, instead of packaging this indirectly into the "lack of effort" rule.

Comment: @l4mpi I don't have any problem with a minimal quality requirement, I never had - but the question was closed based on the "lack of effort", which is at least unfair, but probably isn't even true. If the question had been closed as "lack of minimal understanding", or based on some similar directive, I didn't have a word against this.

Comment: @Cerbrus To search for this, at first he had to be able to separate this important part of the long compiler output. When I started with gcc playing, I wasn't able, but after a _little_ experience, I was. This little experience, which the OP didn't get - yet, and this is what is missing, and the his effort.

Comment: @peterh funny, "lack of minimal understanding" used to be a close reason, that got deleted because we got seen as elitist. We don't ask a LOT of effort, just a minimum. OPs have to understand they are asking people to freely give their time and respect that. Posting an error with no context, no nothing, doesn't show research effort. We are coders, we work in the literal world, with little place to interpretation. If OP doesn't say "I tried", in no way should we assume he did. If it's his first Q here, he had to check he read the help center, who has a nice article on "how to ask"

Comment: @Patrice No. Never is stated clearly, there were a clear requirement existing here, and is wasn't even the reason of the close. And, on my opinion, the "lack of effort" was applied unfairly in this case, and this unfairness now probably expelled a good-standing newbie, who could have got important content to the site.

Comment: @peterh I'm not defending. You keep on complaining people have "no arguments", I give you some. you say I'm "defensive".... honestly..... you just don't wanna hear what people are telling you, so I'll leave it at that. And "good standing newbie"? 1 question? that's "good standing" to you? In any case, you won't change your mind, that much is clear.... So have fun being the only righteous one in a sea of evil ppl who try to keep a good quality Q&A site up ^^

Comment: @peterh You may (or may not) have noticed that this is going absolutely nowhere. Time to stop, perhaps.

Comment: Looking at the linked question as it is, it shows very little to no research effort - so downvoted fairly and justly.  Looking at this question (-40) - the community has disagreed with the ideas brought forward.  **I have also read the extensive comment discussion and are *still* 100% convinced** that the linked question is rubbish an was dv-ed fairly and are totally convinced that the premise of this meta post is nonsense.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's funny that the question in question was sitting at -2 when this was posted, and probably would have stayed at that had it not been posted here. The user who actually posted it hasn't made any comment since they were told a few minutes after posting it what the problem was. They probably got a solution to their problem before you even posted your answer to it, peterh.

Your actions have lead to a *more* "hostile" experience for the new user, not less.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer entirely misses the point, that it was only an example of a more general question. My goal wasn't only to defend the OP, but to ask for the clear reaction of the community in similar cases. @Cerbrus answered clear yes, which I happily accepted - if you had a better idea, I suggest to have better arguments with that. Now I don't have any option as to downvote your answer, and I suggest to delete it.

Comment: You cant down vote my answer? That sounds like a bug. If you picked your example question at random, you picked a very bad example.

Comment: @TZHX He means "he has no other option left BUT to dv your answer"

Comment: I think it was a very good example, when a good question was simply closed unfairly.

Comment: @Patrice Thank you very much the correction.

Comment: The community *unanimously disagrees* about your example being a "good question", and it wasn't even closed when you brought it up here. That you defend it so fervently is surely the cause of all the "off-topic" comments that you're protesting against. For the record (not to clutter up Barts inbox) I have down voted you exactly once on the main site.

Comment: @TZHX Unfortunately, the goal of this question was not save the example question, but to ask for the opinion of community, if it is valid to advice the newbie to a more friendly site. Most of the comments here - included your - entirely missed the focus.

Comment: That 44 people have managed to "miss the focus" of your question suggests that the focus is quite unclear. That you take some down votes to a poor question as a sign of "unfriendly" behaviour further suggests that you miss the focus of the voting system in place on the stack exchange network of sites.

Comment: You, with 3 other people, answered this question, these answers got upvotes, and I even upvoted-accepted it (the one from @Cerbrus). I think, you probably doesn't really like me, but please try to differentiate between a question which is unclear, and between a question which isn't really liked by you. These are different things.

Comment: The moment you linked to that other question, it became part of the point of this question, @peterh. That's how Meta works. This answer _is_ on topic. It may no answer the exact question in your post, but it does explain consequences of you posting it.